# Opencv map predefined GT cordinates to different aspect ratio

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a dataset of eye gluacoma with predefined ground truths of optic disc and optic cup, but the image size in the dataset is way too large, they are around 2045x1752 so the GT cordinates are also as per that cordinate ratio, but am looking to resize the image to lower aspect ratio say 450x400, and relocate the GT cordinates according to a new aspect ratio, but am bit confused with that, so any approch towards this problem would be appreciated.

> *Note: Here the GT cordinates are in seperate csv file, it's not
>   already labled in the dataset image itself.*

Comment: Can you please add some information about the correspondence b/w image pixels and GT co-ordinates? Does each pixel have a corresponding GT co-ordinate? Does each image is of size `2045x1752`? Please add as much information about your data format as possible. Right now it's little unclear how your input and output look like.

Comment: just to clear, GT co-ordinate list is (x,y) tupple which shows the boundaries for optic disc and optic cup on that image, so eventually the co-ordinate list here do have correspondence with image pixels(i.e complete image matrix is 2045x1752 ratio), also not all the images are exact 2045x1752 size, but more or less they are in that range.